# passing parameters to remote beanshell

Tags: parameter-passing, beanshell

I need to pass parameter to **remote** beanshell script which is run through

```
java -cp bsh-2.0b4.jar bsh.Remote http://10.0.0.1/beanshell script.bsh p1 p2 p3
```

call.

Is it somehow possible to read params 'p1', 'p2' and 'p3' from within the `script.bsh`?

p.s. Local params passing through `bsh.args` works fine, but it's unusable with remote scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, you are using [beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/download.html) library. There is no way to do so, according to sources: the utility takes only 2 arguments: the URL and the local script filename. It even does not support several script filenames, as it claim to.

```
public class Remote
{
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception
    {
          if ( args.length < 2 ) {
                   System.out.println("usage: Remote URL(http|bsh) file [ file ] ... ");
                   System.exit(1);
          }
          String url = args[0];
          String text = getFile(args[1]);
          int ret = eval( url, text );
          System.exit( ret );
    }
```

Also the server-side should be aware about the arguments passed.

The ways out for you:

1. Create the script template, in which you will substitute the arguments for the script and save the substitute script to temp dir before passing to `bsh.Remote`
2. Create a remote file, where the script can read arguments from. You need additional communication with remote site to upload this file before calling `bsh.Remote`.